# how to echo a list of file names using ant in a key pair style?

Tags: ant

I have a `FileSet` and want to echo in a `PropertyFile` the names of the files. Like this:

```
file.name.1=foo.txt
file.name.2=bar.pdf
file.name.3=bob.blah
```

I've seen some solutions where the filenames can be concatenated in a single `Property` and then echoed in one step. But since I'm using `PropertyFile` I need to write using `Entry`.

Of course I can use `Echo` and print each filename in a way that emulates a property file, but the problem is the same. How to make the counter and print all the names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't do it using only Ant. There is this old abandoned project [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) that have exactly what I needed.

```
<target name="print.names" >
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

    <var name="counter" value="0"></var>
    <for param="current.file">
        <fileset dir="path/to/dir"></fileset>
        <sequential>
            <var name="aux.name" unset="true"></var>
            <basename file="@{current.file}" property="aux.name"></basename>
            <math operand1="${counter}" operation="+" operand2="1" result="counter" datatype="int"></math>
            <echo file="path/to/output/file.txt" append="true" message="file.name.${counter}=${aux.name}${line.separator}"></echo>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```